# WebSocket Close Packet

Tags: c#

I am trying to send a close packet to my client from my server artificially, what raw value should I send so the client will understand that I am closing the connection? Does it differ between websocket protocols?

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175016/alchemy-forcefully-disconnect-client

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.closeasync.aspx seems appropriate. Please show what you tried and what did not work for you.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the legacy hixie-76 specification, which is different, and explained how you figure out the later frames

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the simplest level - just *close the connection* - that'll work fine.

The very early hixie-76 has a simple sequence for signalling closure: just send the two bytes 0xFF, 0x00 (the first is the frame type, the second is the length).

In all later specifications, frames are a bit more complex; they are broken down as:

- (1 byte) flags and opcode
- (variable number of bytes) mask flag and payload length
- (optional, 4 bytes) mask
- ({length} bytes) payload

For the first part, the opcode we want is 0x08, and this must be combined with the "fin" flag, 0x80 (this just indicates that the frame isn't split over several messages) - so 0x88.

For the second part, we can use a zero-length message, but we need to know whether we are client-to-server (always masked, so we need to use 0x80) or server-to-client (never masked, so we need to use 0x00).

The third part is **only** included if the mask flag is set, so client-to-server; since we aren't sending a payload there is no point inventing a cryptographically secure mask - we can just use 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00.

The fourth is omitted as we are stating zero length.

So: client-to-server: 0x88 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

And server-to-client: 0x88 0x00

Comment: I do have access to the raw protocol layer, I am currently using `process.context.Send(new byte[4] {80,01,00,00}, true, true);` and it seems to work perfectly except that I receive an `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed: Compressed bit must be 0 if no negotiated deflate-frame extension ` error.

Comment: @user I agree with it; where did you get the value 80 from? That is rsv1 and rsv3 set, opcode zero. You need to send opcode 8 with the fin bit set - decimal 136? (Done in my head - I haven't checked that value)

Comment: I am sorry does it differ between protocols? I do not access to the connection, I use Alchemy in C# and stupidly they don't have a method to terminate a connection. Thanks for all the help man! :)

Comment: @user no it doesn't vary: all the versions that use control frames use the ***same*** control frames. I'm still interested in where you got 80 from

Comment: Read it up somewhere. Now when I send 8 I get an: `failed: Received fragmented control frame: opcode = 8`, is it near impossible to terminate it gracefully raw?

Comment: @user you don't send 8 - you send *opcode* 8, with the "fin" bit set. Hence 136. Try sending 136. Also, if anything the next byte should be 0, not 1.

Comment: @user yes, I'm working entirely on paper here, but { 136, 0 } looks like a close frame to me; just those 2 bytes